# how to setup devpi-server for pypi pip searching

Tags: pip, pypi, devpi

I am using a [a devpi-server](http://doc.devpi.net/) to locally cache and install pypi packages using pip. However when I search for packages using the devpi server I get the following error:

pypi.xyz.com is the name of the server

```
ProtocolError: <ProtocolError for pypi.xyz.com:33141/root/pypi/+simple/: 405 Method Not Allowed>
```

Note that install work just fine

Edit: I am using a proxy that is allowed to access pypi.xyz.com by setting http_proxy before calling the pip command. The proxy is working fine and allows access to the pypi.xyz.com server as you can run the pip install commands without any trouble.

pip.conf:

```
[global]

[install]
index-url = http://pypi.xyz.com:33141/root/pypi/+simple/

[search]
index = http://pypi.xyz.com:33141/root/pypi/+simple/
```

Adding the clarifications requested by @JanVlcinsky:
1. Installed devpi using pypi
2. None of the default settings were modified except the port change
3. Protocol Error is in the console when I use pip with the following environment variable set

```
export http_proxy=http://localhost:33128
```

1. Changed port to 33141 Just for some obfuscation security, try to avoid using defaults
2. It is an http_proxy (running locally using squid)

Comment: @askhool Provide more details. How did you install devpi, did you modify some of default settings? Where do you see the "ProtocolError" - on console, in log? Provide complete text ideally with how you call it. Why do you run it on port 33141, when default one is 3141. What is set up of your proxy, what you exactly mean by proxy (is it HTTP proxy?). How it works for other HTTP request like in your browser.

Comment: @JanVlcinsky
1. Installed devpi using pip install devpi

Answer (score 0):

You can find the answer in the "using pip search" section of [the official doc](https://devpi.net/docs/devpi/devpi/latest/+doc/quickstart-pypimirror.html#using-pip-search):

```
pip install -q -U devpi-web
devpi-server --stop
devpi-server --recreate-search-index
devpi-server --start
```